# Probability and statistics 11

Tags: probability

Assume that a person can be born on a Monday with probability 1/3 and
with equal probability any other day of the week. What is the probability
that among 4 randomly selected people, two were born on the same day
and the other two in two other days (for instance, two on Tuesday, one on
Saturday and one on Friday)?

Comment: What have you tried?  Note:  you should clarify whether or not something like "two Tuesdays and two Thursdays" is a success or a fail.

Comment: As a general hint:  because the days are not-equiprobable I'd split it up into cases.  First suppose nobody was born on Monday, then suppose that the pair was Monday, then suppose that one of the non-pair was Monday.

Comment: There is only one pair soif two monday then the other 2 must be also diffenet such as Tuesday and Wednesday ive tried to split into cases but i cant find the finall answer note that i have the final answer which is 0.521

Comment: Well, it's hard to help without seeing your work.  That method should go through so I expect you just have an algebraic error.  Please edit your post to show your work.